# ExtJS 5 - Tooltip with dynamic content

Tags: extjs, tooltip, extjs5

I'm trying to figure out a way to dynamically configure the content of a `tooltip`.  Ideally I'd like to have a function called when the user hovers over the tooltip component.  This function would determine and return the content string and the tooltip would then be displayed with that content.

Specifically, this tooltip is for a tool component (if that matters.)

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/syzecpqp/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sencha's [example page](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/qtips/qtips.html) has a few different types of tooltips, including a dynamic ajax one.

There's also the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tip.ToolTip) page that gives an example of how to change the content by using the "beforeshow" event.  That example is under the "Delegation" heading.

Comment: The second example was exactly what I wanted, thanks.  Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cmm5y0hu/

Comment: For action column buttons you might want to use a `getTip` function (seem to be only available for grids, not for tools): https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.column.Action.html#cfg-getTip